# Remove 'Check Compatibility' from Plugins menu

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

Is there a way to remove the 'Check Compatibility' link that appears under plugins in the plugin menu?

If so, how can I remove the link from a given set of plugins, and alternatively from all plugins at once?

Comment: What link? This doesn't seem to come up in either core code or Codex.

Comment: Are you using WPML? WPML generates that link to check it's database for known compatibility issues with other plugins.

Comment: @Welcher Yes I am. I just updated it and then they appeared. I never linked the two together though. Is there a way to switch it off? P.s. The link is shown below all plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated elsewhere, this is actually part of the WMPL plugin.

To turn it off you can simply deactivate the additional installer plugin which is used to keep WMPL -and other 3rd party apps- up to date.

Comment: The 3rd party installer which in my opinion had some serious flaws, has now been removed from the product.

Answer (score 0):

That is part of WPML's functionality to check for known incompatibilities with 3rd party plugins. To my knowledge, there is no way to toggle that off.